# Python dictionary removed key when using operator

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm working on making a dictionary currently that contains words and phrases (assume a phrase cannot be in the same string, because they can't, bear with me here). Long story short, how do I make a key in a dictionary contain multiple strings? I've tried using "and" between the two strings, but that deletes the key and value as a whole, it seems.

EDIT: Okay, in hindsight, I wasn't very clear on what was happening. Below is pretty much what is happening:

```
def execute(text):
    dic1 = {
        "some word": 1,
        "another word":1,
        "hello" + "world": 5 ##this is what i attempted
    }
```

When I had the "hello" + "world" key printed, it came back as the key being "helloworld", which is not what I want. I want the key to be BOTH strings. I attempted to replace the + with "and", but it deleted the key entirely. (By this, I mean it would replace this key with one next on the list). Basically, how do I make the key consist of two strings so that I am able to call it for another purpose?

Comment: Make it contain a list value

Comment: could you add the code you already tried and state what it should return and what didn't work?

Comment: Hello Alex, an example would be useful. Can you show an example of the input and output.

Comment: What do you expect to get back when you access the key?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MadPhysicist You cannot use list as keys or values, they are unhashable. What he needs to use is a `tuple()`.

Comment: Do you want the key to be multiple strings or do you want the associated value to be multiple strings?

Comment: @PM2Ring _" how do I make a key in a dictionary contain multiple strings?"_ - He wants a key.

Comment: @leaf You're correct that lists can't be used as keys but they can certainly be used as values.

Comment: @leaf I suspect that the OP is using the terminology in a confused way.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah your right, I was wrong in my previous comment. **To the OP:** You need to use an immutable type for your keys. This is because lists are mutable, and are not hashable. Use `tuple()`s instead, which are hashable.

Comment: @leaf. That is only true for keys. Values need not be hashable and can be lists as a consequence. I do it all the time.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I know, I know, PM already corrected me :-)

Comment: @leaf. Sorry, on mobile browser here, not getting proper status updates. Wasn't trying to belabor the point.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Its fine.

Comment: I think Alex needs to clarify the question before it can be answered properly.

Comment: @PM2Ring edited, hopefully clarified well enough. Just let me know what else you need

Answer (score 0):

If you want a key to contain multiple values, you need to use a *sequence*. One may try to use a `list()`, but you cannot. They are mutable. You need to use `tuple()`s instead, which *are* not mutable - or immutable.

```
>>> # list are mutable, which means they cannot be used
>>> # as keys in a dictionary.
>>> {[]:''}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    {[]:''}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> # you need to use tuples instead, which
>>> # are not mutable.
>>> {():''}
{(): ''}
>>> {('a', 'b'):'c'}
{('a', 'b'): 'c'}
>>>
```

The documentation for Python dictionaries also states this:

> Tuples can be used as keys if they contain only strings, numbers, or tuples; if a tuple contains any mutable object either directly or indirectly, it cannot be used as a key. You can’t use lists as keys, since lists can be modified in place using index assignments, slice assignments, or methods like `append()` and `extend()`.

Answer (score 0):

A single `dict` item cannot have two keys. So if you need two keys to access the same value you have to make two items, one for each key. Eg,

```
dic1 = 
{
    "some word": 1,
    "another word": 1,
    "hello": 5,
    "world": 5,
}
```

Note that if you do something like

```
a = ["some", "data"]
dic1 = {"key1": a, "key2": a}
a.append("words")
```

then both `dic1["key1"]` and `dic1["key2"]` will retrieve `["some", "data", "words"]` because both keys are associated with the same list.

---

If you need the key to be some kind of pair of words, you can use tuples for the keys, as shown in leaf's answer. Another option is to use frozensets for the keys - the benefit of doing that is that `frozenset(["hello", "world"])` is equal to `frozenset(["world", "hello"])`, so word order is not significant when looking up an item.